# Rx GroupBy: Remove item or Update exising item not trigger regroup

Tags: system.reactive, reactiveui

```
 private static void TestGroupBy()
        {
            var rxList = new ReactiveList<int>();

            Observable.Merge(rxList.ItemsAdded, rxList.ItemChanged.Select(x => x.Sender) ).GroupBy(i => i%3)
                .Subscribe(group => 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("--> Group {0} is created", group.Key) );
                    int child = 0;
                    group.Subscribe(c => 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(" ------>  Adding child {0} to Group {1} - ChildCnt: {2}", c, group.Key, ++child) );
                        });
                });

            Console.WriteLine("Add 1 to 10... ");
            rxList.AddRange(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });

            Console.WriteLine("Change item 0 to 11, expect to be moved from group 0, to Group 2 ");
            rxList[0] = 11;

            Console.WriteLine("Remove item at 0, expect the item to be removed from the group ...");
            rxList.RemoveAt(0);
        }
```

I have this piece of code here.  I would like the regroup to trigger if item is either removed, or item is replaced with new one.  How do I achieve this?

Comment: You should clarify: Where does your ReactiveList come from, what type of observable is it?

Comment: Could you include in the question an output of your code, and expected output as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to implement item removing using `groupBy` like you want to do. Take a look [at this picture](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html): it seems like you want to alter the elements that have already been pushed to one of the "grouped" streams.

In your case, I would simply create several derived collections (as many as you have groups), with different selectors:

```
 public void Test()
 {
    var source = new ReactiveList<int>();

    var derived1 = source.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x, filter: x => x%3 == 0);
    var derived2 = source.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x, filter: x => x%3 == 1);
    var derived3 = source.CreateDerivedCollection(x => x, filter: x => x%3 == 2);
}
```